# Merge the result of two bool queries using two different sorting (of same type) fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have two different indexes which store data in different structure. I want to combine the results of query on these indexes based on the field of same type but different name in each of these indexes.
for example:
call index has

```
{
  callTime:"2023-03-27T23:16:01Z",
  title:"hello world!",
  type:"ZOOM"
}
```

email index has:

```
{
  timestamp:"2023-03-26T22:06:00Z",
  subject:"Hello World again!",
  bcc:"abc@test.com"
}
```

Now these indices might have lots of data. I want last 25 objects based on some query and then both the indices sorted by callTime/timestamp. It can contain any number of objects from either of these indices as long as they are sorted by callTime/timestamp field and satisfy the query written on their index.

tried using multi search, didn't get anything from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sort Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting) in your query as shown below which will work for your requirements.

I have index 2 documents as given by you in seperate index:

```json
POST call/_doc
{
  "callTime":"2023-03-27T23:16:01Z",
  "title":"hello world!",
  "type":"ZOOM"
}

POST email/_doc
{
  "timestamp":"2023-03-26T22:06:00Z",
  "subject":"Hello World again!",
  "bcc":"abc@test.com"
}
```

Below is **query** which will give expected result, you can update query with condition or add size param for getting specific number of result etc.:

```json
POST call,email/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "if(doc.containsKey('callTime')){return doc['callTime'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()} else if(doc.containsKey('timestamp')){return doc['timestamp'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```json
{
  "took": 575,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "email",
        "_id": "u_SqJocBYGx8nLsboyew",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2023-03-26T22:06:00Z",
          "subject": "Hello World again!",
          "bcc": "abc@test.com"
        },
        "sort": [
          1679868360000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "call",
        "_id": "uvSqJocBYGx8nLsbHyfp",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "callTime": "2023-03-27T23:16:01Z",
          "title": "hello world!",
          "type": "ZOOM"
        },
        "sort": [
          1679958961000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add an alias to time field of one index, eg. add an alias field named 'callTime' of field 'timestamp' in email index, and then search across indexes use 'callTime'

see:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-alias.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html

Comment: Link-only answers tend not to be received well on SO.

Answer (score 0):

## The Summary

There are ways to sort fields of two indices

I. Create an index and reindex documents using:

- a common field (see listing 1)
- a field aliases (as @Mathew advised)
- a common field and the copy_to parameter for source fields

II. Document update:

- creating a common field by update_by_query (see listing 2)

III. Dynamic field:

- sort script (as @Sagar Patel advised)
- runtime_mappings in a search query (see listing 3)

## Sample Documents

```
PUT _bulk
{"create":{"_index":"call","_id":1}}
{"callTime":"2023-03-27T23:16:01Z","title":"hello world!","type":"ZOOM"}
{"create":{"_index":"email","_id":1}}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-26T22:06:00Z","subject":"Hello World again!","bcc":"abc@test.com"}
```

## Listing #1. Reindex documents using a common field

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": ["call", "email"]
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "call_email_common_field"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            if (ctx['_index'] == 'call') {
                ctx['_source']['datetime'] = ctx['_source']['callTime'];
                return;
            }
            if (ctx['_index'] == 'email') {
                ctx['_source']['datetime'] = ctx['_source']['timestamp'];
                return;
            }
        """
    }
}
```

## Listing #2. Update documents with the same script

```
POST /call,email/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": """
            if (ctx['_index'] == 'call') {
                ctx['_source']['datetime'] = ctx['_source']['callTime'];
                return;
            }
            if (ctx['_index'] == 'email') {
                ctx['_source']['datetime'] = ctx['_source']['timestamp'];
                return;
            }
        """
    }
}
```

Query

```
GET /call,email/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "datetime": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "call",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : null,
                "_source" : {
                    "datetime" : "2023-03-27T23:16:01Z",
                    "title" : "hello world!",
                    "type" : "ZOOM",
                    "callTime" : "2023-03-27T23:16:01Z"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1679958961000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "email",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : null,
                "_source" : {
                    "datetime" : "2023-03-26T22:06:00Z",
                    "bcc" : "abc@test.com",
                    "subject" : "Hello World again!",
                    "timestamp" : "2023-03-26T22:06:00Z"
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1679868360000
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

## Listing #3. Runtime Field

```
GET /call,email/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "runtime_datetime": {
            "type": "date",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    Instant ageStart = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
                    ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ageStart, ZoneId.of('Z'));
                    if (doc.containsKey('callTime')) {
                        time = doc['callTime'].value;
                    } else if (doc.containsKey('timestamp')) {
                        time = doc['timestamp'].value;
                    }
                    emit(time.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
                """
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "runtime_datetime", "callTime", "timestamp"
    ],
    "_source": false,
    "sort": [
        {
            "runtime_datetime": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "call",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : null,
                "fields" : {
                    "callTime" : [
                        "2023-03-27T23:16:01.000Z"
                    ],
                    "runtime_datetime" : [
                        "2023-03-27T23:16:01.000Z"
                    ]
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1679958961000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index" : "email",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : null,
                "fields" : {
                    "runtime_datetime" : [
                        "2023-03-26T22:06:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "timestamp" : [
                        "2023-03-26T22:06:00.000Z"
                    ]
                },
                "sort" : [
                    1679868360000
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```